# USB touch screen not working with debian 3.8.13 (BeagleBone Black)

Tags: devices, usb-device, touch-screen

I have a waveshare 7" HDMI touch screen display rev 2.1(touch over USB port and HDMI display) ([link for the product](http://www.waveshare.com/7inch-hdmi-lcd-b.htm)) and I want to interface it with BeagleBone Black.

The manufacturer says the 7" inch touch screen display is driver free (like a mouse). But when I interface it with my BeagleBone Black, display over HDMI is working well but touch is not working.

Device file and event are created for touch screen is created in **/dev/** and **/dev/input/** respectively

```
/dev/hidraw0
/dev/input/event1
```

Then I entered below command to read raw data from **/dev/hidraw0** file by below command

```
xxd -c 25 /dev/hidraw0
```

But got no output data.

Below is the output of **dmesg** command

```
dmesg |grep USB
[    0.734182] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[    0.734189] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    0.734266] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    0.736593] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: MUSB HDRC host driver
[    0.736895] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.736922] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: supports USB remote wakeup
[    0.737045] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.737057] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.737068] usb usb1: Product: MUSB HDRC host driver
[    0.737806] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.889044] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.118512] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using musb-hdrc
[    1.238731] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=0005
[    1.238743] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.253486] hid-multitouch 0003:0EEF:0005.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [BYZHYYZHY By ZH851] on usb-musb-hdrc.1.auto-1/input0
[   13.907878] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.0.auto: MUSB HDRC host driver
[   13.910518] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.0.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[   13.910555] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.0.auto: supports USB remote wakeup
[   13.910678] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[   13.910690] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   13.910702] usb usb2: Product: MUSB HDRC host driver
[   13.920011] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
```

In above output at 1.1 seconds USB touch has been detected.

I am unable to interpret why touch  screen is not working and how to make it work.

Comment: Which kernel version `(uname -r)` are you using?? Can you share output of `xinput`, `evtest` and `lshal` command ? As your input device is being detected correctly by `hid_multitouch` driver, it may just be a small issue of `HAL` policy entry. Probably, setting `evdev` as `input.x11_driver` will solve your problem.